# Template unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, class, templates, error-handling, declaration

I'm working on template class to Array but seems like the function doesn't match the declaration and I can't understand why:

```
template <class Type>
class Array
{
private:
    Type* m_data;
    unsigned int _size;

public:
    template <class Type> Array(unsigned int initial_size); // Function
}
```

As the function itself match the declaration, I even did Ctrl+'.' to let VS do the function but still getting the error. I saw similar porblems but seems like they all used Type in the param which I didn't.

```
template<class Type>
Array<Type>::Array(unsigned int initial_size)
{
    _size = initial_size;
    m_data = new Type(initial_size);
}
```

> 'Array::Array': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Why does the error happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `template` in the constructor declaration:

```
template <class Type> Array(unsigned int initial_size);
```

Just use:

```
Array(unsigned int initial_size);
```

Comment: That could not be done, as you need the namespace **Array<Type>::** and without the **template <class Type>** the Type could not be recognized

Comment: @Ofek.T., I was talking about the declaration in the class, not the implementation.

Comment: Oh alright, when I remove it from the declaration and keep it in the implementation it's fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is no function (constructor) `Array(unsigned int initial_size)` declared in `Array<T>`. There is a constructor **template**: `template <class Type> Array(unsigned int initial_size)`.

So, you have a constructor template inside a class template.

You could define it like this:

```
template<typename Type>
template<typename AnotherType>
Array<Type>::Array(unsigned int initial_size){
```

But since you don't appear to use the template arguement of the constructor template, it's unclear, why it is a template in first place.

If you don't need a constructor template, then I recommend using a regular constructor instead:

```
public:
Array(unsigned int initial_size);
```